# Необходимо выровнять текст как на картинке, как это можно сделать?

Tags: html

Какой нужен код для того, чтобы сделать выравнивание текста как на картинке.
Сейчас код такой:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>About</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="general.html">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">О нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

    <h2>О компании VAGUE</h2>
    <div class="txt">   
        <p>
            Первый номер журнала общественного еженедельника, созданного для состоятельных ньюйоркцев, увидел свет в 1892 году. Имена большинства из 250 акционеров публиковались в «Светском альманахе», среди них были Корнелиус Вандербильт (первый долларовый мультимиллионер), Стёйвесант Фиш (генеральный директор Иллинойской центральной железной дороги), герцог Перси Морган и другие. Основали новый журнал Артур Тюрнюр – юный член светского общества из обеспеченной семьи, у которого уже был журналистский опыт, и Гарри Маквикар, чей прадед Стефан Уитни был крупным оптовиком. Тюрнюр занял должность издателя, а Маквикар, изучавший искусство в Европе, стал арт-директором Vogue. Сначала еженедельник состоял из 16 страниц ин-кварто, однако он был хорошо отпечатан и красиво оформлен. Обложку украшала одна из изысканных картинок, которые стали популярны благодаря журналу Life, размещавшему под ними юмористические диалоги. Цена одного экземпляра (десять центов) позволяла человеку со средним достатком приобрести журнал и узнать, что же происходит в обществе.
        </p>
    </div>
    <p align="right"><a href="#top">Наверх</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Отображается так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так: (чтобы текст был также выравнен)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Загрузите, пожалуйста, Ваш html и css код и уточните, что именно не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно для `<p></p>`задать нужную ширину и выравнивание по ширине (text-align: justify;)

```css
h2 {
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<h2>О компании VAGUE</h2>
<p>
  Первый номер журнала общественного еженедельника, созданного для состоятельных ньюйоркцев, увидел свет в 1892 году. Имена большинства из 250 акционеров публиковались в «Светском альманахе», среди них были Корнелиус Вандербильт (первый долларовый мультимиллионер), Стёйвесант Фиш (генеральный директор Иллинойской центральной железной дороги), герцог Перси Морган и другие. Основали новый журнал Артур Тюрнюр – юный член светского общества из обеспеченной семьи, у которого уже был журналистский опыт, и Гарри Маквикар, чей прадед Стефан Уитни был крупным оптовиком. Тюрнюр занял должность издателя, а Маквикар, изучавший искусство в Европе, стал арт-директором Vogue. Сначала еженедельник состоял из 16 страниц ин-кварто, однако он был хорошо отпечатан и красиво оформлен. Обложку украшала одна из изысканных картинок, которые стали популярны благодаря журналу Life, размещавшему под ними юмористические диалоги. Цена одного экземпляра (десять центов) позволяла человеку со средним достатком приобрести журнал и узнать, что же происходит в обществе.
</p>
```

Comment: Если Вам нужно, чтобы некоторые абзацы выглядели стандартно, а некоторые так, как вы хотите (ограничены по ширине и выравнены по ширине), то присваивайте им классы и задавайте выравнивание через классы